# Laravel CallBack URL cant be found

Tags: php

I am using Laravel and by the way new to the framework, i want to integrate a payment gateway that requires a callback url,

```
Route::post('qp', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\MainAPIController@qp');
```

This is how i defined my route in the api.php and web.php. But unfortunately i cannot find my url which should be https://myApp.com/api/qp. What did i do wrongly.

actually below is my callback function. Am using laravel

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$user=$data->user_id;
$amounts=$data->amount;
$transaction_source=$data->funds_source;
$transaction_source=$data->funds_source;
$transaction_status=$data->status;
$reference=$data->client_ref;
$transaction_date=$data->trans_date;
$narration=$data->naration;
$charges=$data->charges;
if($transaction_status=="SUCCESS"){
}
elseif($transaction_status=="FAILED"){
}
```

Comment: Did you specify the namespace in MainAPIController?

Comment: Not really, the callback url when ever called, it brings "Hoops, looks like something wrong "